# Issues while trying to access url parameters with Twig

Tags: php, twig, slim

I'm currently working with Twig and at some point I want to access parameters which are in the url.
something like that : URL/?list=user

I wanna get the *list* parameter.
I'm using this right now inside twig:

```
{% set v = app.request.get('list') %}
{{ dump(v) }} // return null
```

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Which version of slim are you using? If 3/4, you should be able to use `app.request.getQueryParam('list')` or `app.request.getQueryParams()['list']`

Comment: I'm using v3. 
I stepped uppon these lines before but it's still a NULL result. 
Maybe I'm passing my parameters the wrong way...
I'm using a controller:

return $response->withRedirect($this->container->router->pathFor('home', [], ['list' => 'user'] ));

Comment: The code you are asking for requires you set the variable in the URL, eg. `www.example.com/path/to/route?list=user`

Comment: I do get this kind of url with my variable, the main issue is that I canno't get the url in twig, eg. mydomain/?list=user OR mydomain/?list=yard

Comment: What does `{{ dump(app.request) }}` output?

Comment: {{ dump(app.request) }} gives me NULL

Comment: this is my route :
`$this->get('/:list', 'AuthentificationController:test')->setName('admin.view.change');`

and this is my controller : 

`$param = $request->getQueryParams();
 return response->withRedirect($this->container->
router->pathFor ('home', [], ['list' => $param['list']] ));`

Comment: Well with the code above the query parameter would be directly inject in the variable `list`, `{{ list }}`

Comment: As it seems the request does not get auto-injected in the twig template, I'd suggest to create a `TwigExtension`, here you will be able to get the request and create a function which is able to fetch the query param. An example to do this is found over [here](https://discourse.slimframework.com/t/how-to-get-the-current-route-name-inside-twig-extension/4173)